# mod_authnz_ldap + mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap

1 internet - gate way mod_rewrite
2 localnet site+ ldap  mo_authnz_ldap  192.168.0.16:80

I want to access to 192.168.0.16 when I link to example.com from internet

In local authentication working fine.
But when I try to access from global network it saying me 
Service Temporarily Unavailable

Gateway error log

> (13)Permission denied: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 192.168.0.16:80 (*) failed

Vhost config on gate way

> ```
>   <VirtualHost *:80> 
>    ServerName example.com
>    ProxyRequests Off
>    ProxyPreserveHost On
>    ProxyTimeout 300
>    RewriteEngine on
>    RewriteRule   .*    http://192.168.0.16$1  [L,P]
>   </VirtualHost>
> ```

As I understand gateway trying to access to 192.168.0.16 and it asking it login+password. But it can not give it. Fail.

How can i redirect it? Actually it even not asking login and pass from internet. 
But in local net all good

Comment: What does this have to do with mod_authnz_ldap?

Answer (score 0):

Searching the web for your verbatim error message implies this is often an SELinux error that prevents outgoing tcp connections from httpd.

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied